# why tanstack-query data type is T & ({} | null)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tanstackreact-query

sorry for bad english

I want to make custom search hook using tanstack query v5.

```js
import { useState } from "react"

import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"

type callback<T> = () => Promise<T>

export const useSearchList = <T>(initialValue = "", queryFn: callback<T>) => {
 const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState(initialValue)

 const onSearch = (value: string) => {
   if (value.length === 0) {
     return
   }
   setKeyword(value.trim())
 }

 const { data } = useQuery({
   queryKey: ["search", keyword],
   queryFn,
   enabled: keyword.length > 0,
 })

 if (data === undefined) {
   throw new Error("test")
 }

 return { data, onSearch }
}
```

I want to make data type only 'T', so I throw Error if data is undefined.
but returned data type is `T & ({} | null)`

I tried placeholderData , but it causes type Error.
is any good idea to avoid data type undefined?
and I want to know this hook is available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the data could be still pending. You need to set the `initialData` option to avoid it being undefined.

References:

- [useQuery | TanStack Query Docs](https://tanstack.com/query/latest/docs/framework/react/reference/useQuery)
- [source code of `function useQuery`](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/main/packages/react-query/src/useQuery.ts)
- [source code of `type DefinedInitialDataOptions`](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/7595412a01cbdaae2819c01a925461d12818ece4/packages/react-query/src/queryOptions.ts#L15-L24)
- [source code of `type QueryObserverResult`](https://github.com/TanStack/query/blob/7595412a01cbdaae2819c01a925461d12818ece4/packages/query-core/src/types.ts#L576-L580)